# Notice: Undefined index: node in workflow_tokens()

Tags: drupal-7

I get the above error notice in many pages on my drupal site.

> Notice: Undefined index: node in workflow_tokens() (line 188 of
>   /home/lafune27/public_html/sites/all/modules/workflow/workflow.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in workflow_tokens()
>   (line 189 of
>   /home/lafune27/public_html/sites/all/modules/workflow/workflow.module).

Kindly help.

here's a [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a bug.  There is an issue open for it on [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1485816). See comment #2 in http://drupal.org/node/1485816

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/1418622 Comment #1: I think this should be the patch I should apply. But I dont know how to. A little guidance would help

Comment: Then, I'd suggest making a backup before you patch and make any changes. Drupal's documentation on applying patches: http://drupal.org/patch/apply

Comment: Thanks. :) But my site is hosted in a commercial hosting space. I don't think I can get terminal access to my folder. I also havn't done it via git. Is there a was I could do this by just logging in as administrator? Or have I missed something?

Comment: Then you may have to manually modify the file with the code supplied in the patch.  See this [link](http://www.markusbe.com/2009/12/how-to-read-a-patch-or-diff-and-understand-its-structure-to-apply-it-manually/#how-to-read-a-unified-diff) for more information on how to read the `.patch` file.